# Searching within a subset of data - Solr

Tags: solr

I am new to Solr (Lucene) world. What I am trying to figure out is how would I search within a subset of data? Let me elaborate:

1. I have 10 employees in my Employee table in the database.
2. Each employee has n number of customers that are stored in the Customers table in the same database.
3. When an employee is searching, I want to search only within that employee's customers.

This is not exactly faceted search but I am pretty sure there is a way to do it in Solr looking at all the bells and whistles it has. One way I can think of is to create a separate index for each employee's customer, but that seems quite inefficient.

I will be using this through Solr.NET, but I don't think that should matter much in terms of how this would be implemented but throwing it out there just in case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You woud use [FilterQuery](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fq) - `fq` parameter. With this approach you can easily filter customers for selected employee.

Example:

```
...&fq=employeeId:12
```

In Solr.NET:

```
new SolrQueryByField("employeeId", 12)
```

Comment: Wow, that's really easy. Thanks!