# solr search within subset defined by list of keys

Tags: solr

Is it possible to perform a search with solr within a subset of data? I am using solr combined with tokyo tyrant in python

I read [Searching within a subset of data - Solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183898/searching-within-a-subset-of-data-solr) but I guess it does not really fit my problem because I am not using solr.NET

What I want is to:

1. find the elements of the data set with code = 'xxxx' and
2. I want to perform the search within the a subset of data : data whose id are in a given list / or with id startswith 'yy'

So 1 is not a problem but I do not know how to do 2

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does query like this work for you `q=id:(id1 OR id2 OR id3) OR id:yy*`
You can use `id:(id1 OR id2 OR id3)` to search for ids in the id field and `id:yy*` for the prefix query to check for ids starting with yy

Answer (score 1):

if you have a server their's an administration panel where you can do some request.

but all you have to do to make request is to send an http request with good parameters, basis are explained here.

- http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax
- http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters

Comment: I also found some interesting and very clear information on the use of solr in the following tutorial : http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-solr1/

Comment: its a very old document date 2007 .. given the developments in Solr. So use carefully.